# How to check if a table contains a specific number of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) = SUM(status in (3, 5)) ) AS result 
FROM `match` WHERE round_id = 15
```

this essentially check if the table `match` have all the items with a status `3` or `5` for the round `15`. This works, but I actually want add another condition, in particular if the `result` is `true` I want check that all the records of that table with `round_id = 15` are `20`. How can I perform this?

Comment: Based on the syntax, I added the mysql tag.  If this is not correct, please add the correct tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) = SUM(status in (3, 5)) AND COUNT(*) = 20) AS result 
FROM `match`
WHERE round_id = 15;
```

This checks that there are 20 rows that match the conditions.